# How do I setup Wordpress multi site with CiviCRM mutlisite?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

To what degree does CiviCrm play well with Wordpress multi site installations?

More directly - If I have a multi site install, what is the best way for each 'org' website to seemingly have it's own CiviCrm instance?

Answer (score 3):

I have a Wordpress multi-site that's working quite well.  Note that there are two approaches to Wordpress multi-site: subdomain and subfolder (e.g. "site1.example.org, site2.example.org" vs. "example.org/site1", "example.org/site2".

I posted instructions on the wiki page [Lobo mentioned](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Multi+Site+Installation) for how to set up civicrm.settings.php for subdomain multi-site.  I haven't updated it with subfolder multi-site instructions, but you can find them on my "CiviCRM multi-site checklist" page here: https://hq.palantetech.coop/projects/commons/wiki/CiviCRM_multi-site_checklist.  If you follow the instructions on that page, each site should be more-or-less independent from one another - especially if you install Eileen's excellent [multisite permissioning extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/org.civicrm.multisite) (install from github, not extensions directory!)

Answer (score 0):

Might want to check:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Multi+Site+Installation

search for "wordPress multi" on that page